# How do I add images into the "header content" class with a block?

Tags: magento-2.1.3, home-page

I have a theme that extends luma. It is called "Custom Dev" and it is in "adventist_store" folder. I want to replace the logo at the top with a block. (I'm doing this because I want to have two logos next to each other on one store and I want to center the logos) bassically I want to replace the "header content" class on the store page with my own block, or have the block go inside "header content"

I have almost been able to do this by attemping to follow this: https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/adding-blocks-to-head-section/ maybe I'm not understanding it.

Here's parent theme:

**vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">148</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock> 
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
        <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

And I'm extending it like so:

**app/design/frontend/Magento/adventist_store/Magento_Theme/templates/header_template.phtml**

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_header_custom')->toHtml();?>
```

**app/design/frontend/Magento/adventist_store/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright ï¿½ 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">

        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block-header" after="header">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_header_custom</argument>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">%Magento_Theme::header_template.phtml%</argument>

            </arguments>
        </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="logo" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">

                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block-footer" after="footer_links">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_footer_custom</argument>
                        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">%Magento_Theme::footer_template.phtml%</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

However this puts the logos above "header content" right after the tag: 
`<body data-container="body" . . .`  I have to remove the header.panel: `<referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true"/>` otherwise it appears as a grey thing between my logos and "header content" I would rather not have to remove the grey header.panel and just have my block inside the "header content" class. Thanks.

Comment: add your block to the "header-wrapper" container instead of "head.additional".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Aaron Allen. I added my block to the "header-wrapper" container instead of "head.additional" and it works.

So I changed this:

`<referenceBlock name="head.additional">`

to this:

`<referenceBlock name="header-wrapper">`

I was not aware that you could do that directly to the classes you see in html divs and I didn't realize it was already doing that but just using a "." in between the classes:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html