# my theme stopped working after I switched back to the tip of the branch from an older git commit

Tags: parent-child-theme

So I have backups of all the files in the **Magento root folder** and tried **overwriting the current Magento folder** with the backup folder and it still doesn't recognize the changes I've made in my child theme. My setup is here:

[How do I add images into the "header content" class with a block?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155604/how-do-i-add-images-into-the-header-content-class-with-a-block)

I have tried setting the theme to other themes and no theme and clearing the cache both times and then switching back to mine and it doesn't recognize my theme unless I restore from a database backup from before switching to and from the old git commit. (it really seems like the database somehow got corrupted when I switched commits) Any ideas of what might cause this? This problem can cause people to loose a lot of work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Backup your Code and DB before making these changes**

It might be worth deleting the theme from the database, if you view the `theme` table you should see a list of themes and IDs.

[image]

Make sure your theme is not the currently selected one otherwise you will get errors, and then delete your theme from the DB.

Now clear all caches, delete `var/view_preprocessed` and `pub/static/frontend` and load a page on the frontend.

Now try and select your theme again.

I haven't had this exact problem but I had a similar one and doing this did resolved it.

Comment: Thanks very much this worked :) except I deleted both my child theme and parent theme in the database (not sure if that made a difference)